# CSS: Two-color background

Tags: html, css

This might not be the best title, but I am having a hard time trying to find the appropriate one. Basically, what I need is to have a two-color background image, with the breakpoint set to a specific position.

Here's what I have right now:

[image]

Which can be tested in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8p3ahb3/).

And this is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

One thing though, is that the slant in this bar needs to be aligned with the logo, as shown below:

[image]

If there was no slant, this might be easier, but I have not found a way to achieve the desired behavior. What I tried doing was creating a div with a background color, and inside that div, a second one that would be placed on top containing the image.

```
<div class="line-container">
      <div class="line">                
      </div>
</div>

.line-container{
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-color: #009b3a;
}
.line{
  background-image: url('http://s8.postimg.org/fc0umdjut/image.png');
  display: block;
  width: 50m;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 10px;
}
```

But position and color to the sides are wrong, as shown in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8p3ahb3/3/):

Any advise?

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/f8p3ahb3/5/

Comment: Thank you @NenadVracar! That was really helpful! +1

Comment: @Nenad, I still have an issue with position, though. The slant should always be aligned with the logo, and I cannot seem to get that to work with the solution above. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like a job for a gradient.

```
background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg,  #1e5799 0%, #1e5799 48%, #2989d8 48%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  #1e5799 0%,#1e5799 48%,#2989d8 48%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(45deg,  #1e5799 0%,#1e5799 48%,#2989d8 48%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
```

Simply add this to your css class and change the colors within accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. The problem is the image has a slant instead of a straight line.  Is this possible using gradients?

Comment: I've just updated the answer to include a horizontal slant at the point where the two colors connect! This is done by rotating the gradient.

Comment: Thank you @Nick. I still have an issue with position, though. The slant should always be aligned with the logo, and I cannot seem to get that to work with the solution above. Any thoughts?

Comment: You'll need to adjust the two 48%'s in all the gradients to a number around 20%. If the site is responsive, you'll have to use media queries to position it in the proper spot.

Comment: Thanks Nick. But when using %, the position varies according to the screen size. Zooming in/out shows what I mean in this new [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8p3ahb3/7/)

Answer (score 2):

Even though the accepted answer is great, I wanted to share an alternative to using gradients.

Here's an option using the `::before` pseudo-class with a CSS `border` trick to get the angled portion. You can adjust the "angle" by tweaking the border widths. The `width` property on the pseudo-element can be adjusted, as needed.

```css
div {
  background: green;
  height: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

div:before {
  background: darkgreen;
  border: solid transparent 0;
  border-bottom-width: 10px;
  border-right-color: green;
  border-right-width: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: '';
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: +1 Thank you @Quantastical! This is a great solution. However, I cannot seem to adjust the width of the pseudo-element so that the slant is always shown at the same position in regards tot he logo. Any thoughts on that? Here's an updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f8p3ahb3/6/) with your suggestions to make things easier: